# How can I set up potentially dozens of cameras rendering to targets without killing performance?

Tags: unity

I'm thinking through how I'd do a particular trick for playing cards with animated 3D faces. Setting up a single card is pretty trivial. I would create another camera somewhere, maybe restrict some layers so it'll only show what I want it to show so I don't have to worry what's behind it, put an object in front of it that is the basis of the card, have the camera render to a texture, and put that texture on a quad (the card) with the same aspect ratio. Now whenever the main camera views the card, regardless of angle, the card displays what the other camera sees.

I don't believe this approach would scale well as I'd have to duplicate everything for every card. The way I imagine it, there could be dozens of cards visible at once so every frame would require rending all of them. Even at low qualities that sounds bad for performance. Also the main reason I want to animate cards is to have them respond to input and actions happening to the cards so two instances of the same card won't show exactly the same thing. Another thing is where would I place all these cameras and their models in the 3D space so that they won't see each other? I could put them on top of each other and use layers to only capture what I want but something doesn't feel right about having dozens of layers.

How would I begin to pull this off on a scale of dozens of cards?

Comment: What goes against just putting the models where the cards are..? Or even going 2D right away?

Comment: The card is a flat quad but the face of the card shows a 3D model like the card is a window into a 3D space. Actually putting the 3D model at the cards breaks the illusion. I'll add pictures when I get a chance.

Comment: Pictures would help. Off-hand I'd say "keep the render size small."

Comment: *"I don't believe this approach would scale well"* - have you tried?

Comment: You could put the 3D model behind the card and use stencils to create a one-way “portal” - making your model only visible through the portal in the card: https://answers.unity.com/questions/590800/how-to-cullrender-to-through-a-window.html Or, if you want your 3D object to be flat on the card, you could just put it on the card and set z scale to a tiny value.